# How to get Wordpress post with title, content and featured image using mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Hi I know this question may seems familiar but please read the full question.
I want to get Wordpress post title,featured image,content using a mysql query.
I tried many queries but I'm getting errors.

there is no error and MySQL query returns empty. I am using Wordpress version 4.5.2.

I found this query but it is giving me an empty result.

```
    SELECT p1.*, wm2.meta_value 
    FROM wp_posts p1 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm1 ON (
    wm1.post_id = p1.id
    AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    )
    LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta wm2
    ON (
    wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
    AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    )LEFT JOIN
   wp_term_relationships wtr
   ON
 (
    object_id=p1.id
   )
   WHERE
   p1.post_status='publish'
   AND p1.post_type='post'
   AND 'term_taxonomy_id'='454'
   ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC
   LIMIT 0,10
```

How can I improve this query to return results?

Comment: You should show us your database structure, as well as checking for yourself if your MySQL is returning any error notifications when you run the query.

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: there is no error and mysql query returns empty and wordpress version is 4.5.2

Comment: Take a look into $wpdb->get_results("INSERT SQL QUERY HERE").

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in SQL's WHERE clause:

```
AND 'term_taxonomy_id'='454'
```

The string `'term_taxonomy_id'` will never be equal to the string `'454'`.

First, to check, remove this condition entirely from your query. If you get results back and you still want to filter by this `taxonomy_id` then remove the single quote marks around the field name:

```
SELECT p1.*,
    wm2.meta_value
FROM wp_posts p1
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm1 ON (
        wm1.post_id = p1.id
        AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
        )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm2 ON (
        wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
        AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
        AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON (object_id = p1.id)
WHERE p1.post_status = 'publish'
    AND p1.post_type = 'post'
    AND term_taxonomy_id = '454'
ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

In MySQL you can use backticks around field names, but single quotes are used around string literals. If you mix those up, you'll be in trouble.

If you are still not getting results consider removing the `p1.post_status` and `p1.post_type` restrictions to see if you get results back and tweak accordingly.

Comment: thank you sir. worked like a charm!..do me one more favor how can i do this by multiple category id?

Comment: I'm not sure what a category id is. It's been years since I last worked with Wordpress. However... if you wanted to do this for multiple Taxonomy's you could change the `and term_taxonomy_id = '454'` to something like `and term_taxonomy_id in ('454','455','456')` The same logic would work for whatever the `category id` is (Assuming that it's a field in one of the tables already joined in.